# unity 3d game using youtube videos api

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

[youtube video selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnj5k.png)
[youtube video played on background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH4nW.png)

hello so i want to ask few questions , i have managed and developed a game , me and my developing team to use youtube video player api and use the player to select music and then hit the play button to play the arrows game while video and music played on the background.
this is the main idea of the game, were you have songs from youtube that we add using youtube link and it just loads the video and streams it using youtube api java files that they provide for developers and we let players play the video and play the arrows that we have built our selfs.

we dont use or modify or change or download any files from youtube.
all the images, videos, sound are loaded through youtube API for android.

are we allowed to have this and to develop this game for android and IOS and let poeple download it and play it ?

thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, legal advice is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: i asked about legal stuff coz i saw that youtube asks for that using their youtube livestreaming and android youtube api tag, lol

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't circumvent ads on any videos/music and don't claim it as your own, I don't see why not? Youtube is a platform for viewing, not stealing. So if you're just viewing, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

so as i said we dont run ads inside the video, we just load it using their api they provide for developers.
you choose the song > loads from youtube > we get info like image > we sync arrows related to the song length and current song time (all info loaded from youtube api and we save them on the script) then we have the arrows script that we developed it starts based on the info we get from youtube song
and when the song starts the arrows starts and start spawning the arrows based on an xml file that we create.

so after the user played the game he will get music credits based on how good he did and how many stars he collected (max of 5 stars) so he can buy avatars for him or unlock new songs to play. or choose to buy vip access and play all free.

so this idea is a combination of different games that we already saw on market 
1) flash flash revolution (4 arrow rythem game like DDR)
2) tap tap reborn 2 (mobile game that uses youtube api as we do but it has guitar hero style) its already on market with ads/vip/coins to unlock and play music.
3) "just dance now" on mobile (stars and score and music credit)